# How to save just the first element that satisfies certain condition in a for loop without stopping it

Tags: python, list

```
def sum(x,y):
    R=[x+y,x*y]
    return R
L=[1,2]
P=[]
for i in range(1,1000):
    k=sum(*L)
    P.append(k)
    L=k
```

I wish to save the first list L whose second coordinate is greater than, say, 20, but i don't want to stop the process of appending to P in the way. So, to add

```
if L[1]>20:
   u=L
   break
```

won't work for me.

Comment: What does the program suppose to do? And are you sure you do not need i (loop variable) in the body of loop? Please provide an explanation on what you are about to do

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another condition to the `if L[1]>20` line, so you get the first (and only the first) time the value is exceeded *and* don't bother with the break, since you don't want to stop processing.

Simple change would be to initialize `u = None`, and then have your `if` succeed only if u is still None:

```
def sum(x,y):
    ...
L=[1,2]
P=[]
u = None
for i in range(1, 1000):
    k=sum(*L)
    P.append(k)
    L=k
    if u is None and L[1] > 20:
        u = L
print "First:", u
```